# Convert a JSON object to a STRUCT

Tags: sql, json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it possible to do something like the following in BigQuery:

```
SELECT CAST(JSON '{"x": 3}' AS STRUCT<x INT>)
```

Or basically, how do I get json data into a typed value? I was hoping I could do:

```
SELECT AS STRUCT STRUCT(3 as x, 4 as y).*
```

But even that gives me:

```
SELECT AS STRUCT JSON '{"x": 3}'.*
```

> Dot-star is not supported for type JSON at [1:18]. The closest I've gotten is with a manual specification:

```
WITH json AS (
  SELECT JSON '{"x": 3, "y": true}' val
) SELECT STRUCT(json.val.x AS INT64, json.val.y AS BOOL) FROM json
```

Comment: i love your questions and I hate your questions for the same reasons - they are challenging, sexy but too generic so it is really hard to figure out what exactly your use case :o) maybe you can provide simple example of input data and expected output so it will be easier to swallow :o)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would work, but this is what I would try:

1. define the schema of your BigQuery table using [JSON schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#specifying_a_json_schema_file)
2. create a [JavaScript user-defined function (UDF)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure) whose input is the JSON string
3. parse the JSON string in the JavaScript UDF

Comment: Could you show an example? I'm not sure that that's what I need. Also, what does the JSON Schema (schema on write) have to do with typing a json literal (schema on write) ?

Comment: I wrote JSON schema because I thought about reading it from the JavaScript UDF and use it to understand which data type to use. But as I said I am not sure it can be done. Since BigQuery table functions can only accept scalar parameters, as far as I know UDF are the only option to achieve something like this. Could you maybe add a bit of context to your question? Why do you want/need to cast a JSON string?